# Expectation of Transposed random variable

Tags: probability, expectation

Suppose that the random variable X is uniformly distributed on the interval [0, 1])
(i.e X ∼ U(0, 1)) distribution and suppose that
Z = min$(2, 2X^2 + 1)$ .

(a) Explain why Z does not have a density function.

(b) Find E(Z).

my p.d.f for Z is      Z=$2x^2+1$ for $0<x<1$ i don't get why Z doesn't have a pdf and also i dont get how to do part B please help.

Comment: Why do you think the PDF for Z is 2x^2+1 for 0<x<1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A continuous random variable has an individual probability of zero at any one single point.

but according this the probability at x=$1/sqrt(2)$

that makes it discreet at one single point hence the above doesn't have a pdf.

thanks to my friend i found the the solution

Answer (score 1):

I agree that Z does have a density function but it is not what you say, its this:

$$Z=f(x)=\begin{cases}
2x^2+1&,0\le x\le \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\\
2&,\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\lt x\le1\\
0&,\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

For Part B

$$E(z)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x)dx$$

Comment: Hi u r right according to me about the function but the lecturer mentioned on the question that it doesn't have a pdf.

Comment: Looks like a pdf to me

Comment: Semantics shmantics. It is a mixed discrete-continuous density. I wouldn't call it a 'pdf' (continuous), and I wouldn't call it a 'pmf' (discrete), but I would still say it has a density ... just a special type of one (mixed continuous discrete).

Comment: This seems to use the "fact" that if X is U(0,1) then Z=f(X) has density f. This "fact" is far from being true (upvotes on math.se as sweet as ever).